# how can I send data from python to javascript?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to build a command line tool via Python native, but I am also trying to build a gui-based web technology. How can I send a simple `print("hello world")` to `html/css/js` pages without using Flask, Jinja, or Django? If it's not possible, what is the best way to handle the server side bot from the gui?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is a library in python for this. The package is called [Eel](https://github.com/ChrisKnott/Eel), which you can design your GUI in html/css/javascript and have the backend logic in python.

Exposing your python function to your javascript file is extremely easy with this package with the following code,

```
@eel.expose
def my_python_function(a, b):
    print(a, b, a + b)
```

Similarly, any Javascript functions which are exposed like this

```
eel.expose(my_javascript_function);
function my_javascript_function(a, b, c, d) {
  if (a < b) {
    console.log(c * d);
  }
}
```

which can be retrieved in python by

```
print('Calling Javascript...')
eel.my_javascript_function(1, 2, 3, 4)  # This calls the Javascript function
```

Comment: Library recommendations are not allowed on SO and the question itself is off topic and shouldn't be answered anyway.